# Using SSL with redirects from non http causes redirect loop?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I recently setup letsencrypt with my site, and the SSL works perfectly. However, when I set Nginx to redirect HTTPS to HTTPS, I get a redirect loop where when you visit the website and refresh the URL changes back and forth from `example.com` to `https://example.com`.

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html;        

    # ssl_certificate, etc...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly here that causes the redirect loop?

Comment: What is the output of `curl -LI http://example.com/some/path`? (Substitute suitable values for `example.com` and the path)

Comment: I "fixed" it, turns out cloudflare was redirecting to non-https whenever you attempt to use https.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add *ssl on;* under the line listen 443 ssl; and disable disable SSLv3

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl on;
server_name example.com;
ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location / {
  rewrite     ^(.*)   https://example.com$1 permanent;
}
...
```

Or you can also use *return* its way faster than *rewrite* in niginx location blocks:

```
location / {
  return ^(.*)   https://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Once SSL Done You can test your ssl certificate at https://www.ssllabs.com

To create chain certificate:

```
 cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt

 ssl_certificate     www.example.com_chain.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
```

Comment: Use `return` like OP does instead of the `rewrite`. See [nginx pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites).

Comment: Yes correct it batter then rewrite !